# Tengo una duda que en la clase avion crear un arreglo que posea capacidad maxima pasajeros siendo diferentes clases

Tags: java, array

**Avion**

```
public class Avion{
private int matricula;
private String modelo;
private String marca;  

public Avion(){
}
public Avion(int matricula, String modelo, String marca ){
    this.matricula=matricula;
    this.modelo=modelo;
    this.marca=marca;
}
public void setMatricula(int matricula){
    this.matricula=matricula;
}
public int getMatricula(){
    return matricula;
}
public void setModelo(String modelo){
    this.modelo=modelo;
}
public String getModelo(){
    return modelo;
}
public void setMarca(String marca){
    this.marca=marca;
}
public String getMarca(){
    return marca;
}


public String toString(){
    return this.getMarca()+" "+this.getModelo()+" "+this.getMatricula()+" "+this.getModelo();
}
}
```

**Pasajero**

```
public class Pasajero{

public String rut;
public int edad;
public String nombre;
public String apellidoPaterno;
public String apellidoMaterno;


public Pasajero(){
}
public Pasajero (String rut, int edad, String nombre, String apellidoPaterno, String apellidoMaterno){
    this.rut=rut;
    this.edad=edad;
    this.nombre=nombre;
    this.apellidoPaterno=apellidoPaterno;
    this.apellidoMaterno=apellidoMaterno;
}    

public void setRut(String rut) {
    this.rut = rut;
}
public String getRut(){
    return rut;
}
public void setEdad (int edad){
    this.edad=edad;
}
public int getEdad(){
    return edad;
}
public void setNombre(String nombre){
    this.nombre=nombre;
}
public String getNombre(){
    return nombre;
}
public void setApellidoPaterno(String apellidoPaterno){
    this.apellidoPaterno=apellidoPaterno;
}
public String getApellidoPaterno(){
    return apellidoPaterno;
}
public void setApellidoMaterno (String apellidoMaterno){
    this.apellidoMaterno=apellidoMaterno;
}
public String getApellidoMaterno(){
    return apellidoMaterno;
}
public String toString(){
    return this.getNombre()+" "+this.getApellidoPaterno()+" "+this.getApellidoMaterno()+" "+this.getEdad()+" "+this.getRut();
} 
}
```

La duda es que tengo mi clase avion y necesito crear un arreglo que me indique la capacidad maxima del avion pero que este arreglo se llene con la clase pasajero y nose como hacerlo ya que son clases diferentes (Estoy usando Bluej)

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Comment: Cual es el problema? usa el boton [edit] para agregar la informacion sobre el problema especifico

Answer (score 2):

Tenes que agregar un par de cosas a tu clase avion:

Necesitas declarar los pasajeros, para eso te alcanza con hacer:

```
Pasajero[] LosPasajeros;
```

Esto a nivel de clase.

Y despues en el constructor del avion, vas a necesitar una propiedad que sea la cantidad maxima de pasajeros y hacer:

```
LosPasejeros = new Pasajeros[CantidadMaximaDePasajeros]
```

de esa manera tendras un arreglo de pasajeros. Tambien vas a tener que agregar a tu clase avion, un metodo para agregar los pasajeros a este vector.